# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Hi I am getting the following exception

> "Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

can you please help me out in this

```
//Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.persistance.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.persistance.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.persistance.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
```

**the following is my code :**

**Student.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;    

@Entity
@Table(name = "Test", catalog = "Demo", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")
         })
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer stuId;
    private String stuName;
    private String stuDepartment;
    private String stuAddress;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Integer stuId, String stuName,String stuDepartment, String stuAddress) {
        this.stuId=stuId;
        this.stuName = stuName;
        this.stuDepartment=stuDepartment;
        this.stuAddress=stuAddress;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)

    public Integer getStuId() {
        return stuId;
    }

    public void setStuId(Integer stuId) {
        this.stuId = stuId;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getStuName() {
        return stuName;
    }

    public void setStuName(String stuName) {
        this.stuName = stuName;
    }

    @Column(name = "Department", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getStuDepartment() {
        return stuDepartment;
    }

    public void setStuDepartment(String stuDepartment) {
        this.stuDepartment = stuDepartment;
    }

    @Column(name = "Address", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getStuAddress() {
        return stuAddress;
    }

    public void setStuAddress(String stuAddress) {
        this.stuAddress = stuAddress;
    }       
}
```

**App.java**

```
package com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations;

import org.hibernate.Session;    
import com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.persistance.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
         System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + MySQL");
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

         session.beginTransaction();
         Student stu = new Student();    

         stu.setStuId(2);
         stu.setStuName("Raghaav");
         stu.setStuDepartment("CSE");
         stu.setStuAddress("GUNTUR");

         session.save(stu);
         session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.persistance;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }    
}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.ihub.Hidernate_annotations.Student"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the following are dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>      

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>   

  <!--    MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    Hibernate library dependecy end -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency>     
  </dependencies>
```

Please help me out

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The AnnotationConfigiuration is deprecated, Use Configuration instead

```
          return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Not working  gives the following exception "An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.ihub.Hibernate_annotations.Student"/>"

Comment: what is the package of your Student class, i see the package you are using is Hidernate_annotations not Hibernate_annotations

Comment: sorry for that, that was misspell    name of package is Hidernate_annotations

Answer (score 0):

I think the error because you have different hibernate versions in maven's pom.xml. Leave only one hibernate version (Preferably latest) and build again. Also make sure that all hibernate dependencies are same version (Hibernate, hibernate-core, etc.)